# QFileDialog.getSaveFileName() error in Plugin code for QGIS

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-plugins, oserror

I'm working with Plugins Builder to create a simple plugin with QGIS3 "SaveAttributes", I'm following the official tutorial on [QGIS Tutorials](http://www.qgistutorials.com/fr/docs/building_a_python_plugin.html).

I'm installed Python 3 and Python 2 is already installed with ArcGIS, I have installed also the PyQt5 and Qt Creator. (I give details because I think that the error was not provided by the code)

The error I got:

> TypeError: setText(self, str): argument 1 has unexpected type 'tuple'
> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "C:/Users/REDA DRISSI/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python/plugins\reda\module.py", line 190, in select_output_file
> self.dlg.lineEdit.setText(filename)
> TypeError: setText(self, str): argument 1 has unexpected type 'tuple'

For this code:

> ```
> def select_output_file(self):
> ```

```
    filename = QFileDialog.getSaveFileName(self.dlg, "Select output file ","", '*.txt')
    self.dlg.lineEdit.setText(filename)
```

I tried to use `str()` function :

```
self.dlg.lineEdit.setText(str(filename))
```

Gives this Error:

> OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument: "('C:/Users/REDA DRISSI/Desktop/DATA/finaldd/reda.txt', '*.txt')"

I think the problem is related to the default version of Python used by windows and `QVariant`, but I don't know how to resolve the problem.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try

```
self.dlg.lineEdit.setText(filename[0])
```

instead of

```
self.dlg.lineEdit.setText(filename)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Can you elaborate on why this works better than the original code? A link to the relevant docs and an explanation of the return value of `getSaveFileName` would be really good.

Comment: for my test case it stored ('E:/test.txt', '*.txt') in filename but what you wanted was probably  'E:/test.txt' which could be accessed by filename[0]

Comment: if this answers your question please close this question by accepting this answer

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help,i tried to change in the resources.py PyQt5 instead of PyQt4, i used the documentation of the PyQt5 to solve the problem.

Answer (score 6):

QGIS 2 and QGIS 3 use PyQt4 and PyQt5, respectively. In PyQt4, `QFileDialog.getSaveFileName()` method returns filename string like `"c:/path/to/file.txt"`. In PyQt5, that method returns a tuple contains file path and filter string like `("c:/path/to/file.txt", "*.txt")`. So to get filename, you should use `filename[0]` in `setText()` method:

`self.dlg.lineEdit.setText(filename[0])`

Or, because `getSaveFileName()` method returns a tuple with two elements, you can use related line as @Matthias states in comments:

```
def select_output_file(self):
    filename, filter_string = QFileDialog.getSaveFileName(self.dlg, "Select output file ","", '*.txt')
    self.dlg.lineEdit.setText(filename) # without [0]
```

Strangely, [Qt Documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qfiledialog.html#getSaveFileName) doesn't state that.

Comment: The PyQt signature differs from the Qt signature for this method, that's the reason for not stating that. What's not accurate here is the [PyQt5 documentation for QFileDialog](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt5/api/qfiledialog.html).

Comment: I usually use Qt Documentation and I was not aware of PyQt Docs. But I noticed that PyQt Docs is redirecting into Qt Docs. According to [this statement](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt5/pyqt4_differences.html#qfiledialog), `getSaveFileName()` are not supported in PyQt5, but it works in QGIS 3. I'm confused.

Comment: I don't like the PyQt5 documentation very much, so I also always refer to the Qt documentation which is 90% accurate, but still cannot be blamed for not being accurate on derived products ;)

I think the statement you linked to basically said that the PyQt5 `getSaveFileName()` method was already available as `getSaveFileNameAndFilter()` in PyQt4.

Sidenote, I'd probably fix this by using `filename, filter_string = QFileDialog.getSaveFileName`.