# QGIS 3.4.4 - PyQt 5 - Browsing button doesn't react with QFileDialog.getSaveFileName()

Tags: qgis-plugins, qgis-3, pyqt5

I'm trying to work through the tutorial : http://www.qgistutorials.com/en/docs/building_a_python_plugin.html to build a plugin in QGIS 3.4.4. and to implement it with PyQt5 (instead of PyQt4 library in the tutorial).

after many trials, research and errors I managed to get to step 24 of the tutorial but the problem is that once I've put the push button with Qt Creator, I've added some code in "__init__" :

```
def __init__(self, iface):
    [...]
    #for the ... button to be triggered
    self.dlg.lineEdit.clear()
    self.dlg.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.select_output_file)
```

Then, I've added the function "select_output_file" in order to select a file to put in my dialog window :

```
def select_output_file(self):
    #Called when the user presses the ... button
    filename,_ = QFileDialog.getSaveFileName(self.dlg, "Select output file ","", '*.txt')
    self.dlg.lineEdit.setText(filename)
```

I've added an underscore ,_ as QFileDialog.getSaveFileName() returns a tuple compared to the PyQt4 version.

After many searches and trials I can't figure out how to make this button work.

Comment: Perhaps this post might help: [QFileDialog.getSaveFileName() error in Plugin code for QGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/280094/qfiledialog-getsavefilename-error-in-plugin-code-for-qgis)

Comment: I modified but it didn't work either

Comment: What happens? Do you receive an error?

Comment: The problem is that it doesn't react at all, no error in QGIS or python and no window to appear even when I click on the pushbutton

Comment: Put the lines you have shown from the `initGui()` function and place them inside the `run()` function then reload your plugin and try again.

Comment: when i put the code of `initGui()` function in the `run()`function, the button still doesn't work, it just duplicates my plugin in the toolbar once I launch it
I still can't upload any file yet

Comment: Sorry, I was unclear. I meant moving this line `self.dlg.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.select_output_file)` but it should still work so the problem is probably elsewhere. If you put the code back into `initGui()` and change `filename,_` to just `filename`, does it make a difference?

Comment: hmm not really it seems to get worse, I don't even have my layer in my combobox anymore...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally found out,

With QGIS 3 there's already a file selection custom widget in Qt designer. So I just took it and the used the `.ui` file in order to interact with the QFileDialog

In pyQGIS 3, no need to change the original "file.py" plugin file but you'll have to modify the "file_dialog.py" generated with plugin builder to interact with the Qt designer file created

If you want to succeed, the tutorial is still available for PyQt4 but for QGIS 3 and for PyQt5, you'll need to think as a PyQt5 program to make it